# Get Row value from custom gridview when checkbox is checked

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing apps in Codeigniter, i am stuck in some code...i just want to know how can i get complete row values if any one check the checkbox and submit, so i should get row value of  selected checkbox....

Comment: you can check the my gridview output http://www.emsoftware.in/sample.png

Comment: have you created this gridview or used some plugin

Comment: using codeigniter table method

Answer (score 0):

You can use array for while creating rows, use name for your each row's input field as array and when you submit the your form loop over your checkbox array and get the values from other elements using the same key which selected checkbox is having